# How to show Marker in Android Google Map at the Edges?

Tags: android, google-maps, marker

I want to show Marker in the Google Map. Its position will always be at edges of screen of device, pointing to a Lat/Lng, which is outside of the current map view?
When the user drag in that direction, Marker will be gone if that Lat/Lng is visible. Else that Marker will continuously pointing to device edge.

I have found a way to show the Marker in the center. But could not find a way, how to show at the edges?

```
@Override
public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
    Log.d(TAG, "OnCameraChangeListener");
    mMap.clear();
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(cameraPosition.target)).setTag("Center");

    LatLngBounds bounds = mMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;


}
```

Thanks,
Ajeet Singh

Answer (score 0):

You can move your marker to center by the following code

```
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlng));
```

latlng is your location of the marker.

Comment: I don't want to show all markers present in my screen. I want to show few markers which some proper zoom level. But if some Marker are out-side of Map Screen, then I want to show a pointer kind image OR may be a hanging marker at the edges of the screen. Which will continuously point to that marker which is outside of the view port of map.

Comment: if you use map.clear() it will clear all your markers???? Do you want to clear All your markers and put it again???

Comment: Yes may be ... But the the real problem is that ... How will I show "A Hanging Pointer" at the edges of the device screen towards a Marker which lies outside of Map View Port? Since I know the Lat/Lng of the Marker which is outside of the view port, Is there some way from which I can calculate Distance, Angle, and show it at Edge of screen.